# Can not read all messages from modem

Tags: java, file-handling

I need help to read all inbox messages using the command AT+CMGL="ALL". With my java code, I can only get two messages shown
up. Actually there is 10 messages when I try the command in HyperTerminal.

This my code :

```
    /*
     * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
     * and open the template in the editor.
     */
    package consoledmt;

    /**
     *
     * @author user
     */
    import javax.comm.*;
    import java.util.*;
    import java.io.*;
    public class Main {

    public Main() {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Enumeration portIdentifiers = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();
        CommPortIdentifier portId = null; // will be set if port found
        String wantedPortName = "COM17";
        while (portIdentifiers.hasMoreElements()) {
            CommPortIdentifier pid = (CommPortIdentifier) portIdentifiers
                    .nextElement();
            if (pid.getPortType() == CommPortIdentifier.PORT_SERIAL
                    && pid.getName().equals(wantedPortName)) {
                portId = pid;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (portId == null) {
            System.err.println("Could not find serial port " + wantedPortName);
            System.exit(0);
        }

        SerialPort port = null;
        try {
            port = (SerialPort) portId.open("Wavecom", 10000); // Wait max. 10
        } catch (PortInUseException e) {
            System.err.println("Port already in use: " + e);
            System.exit(1);
        }
        try {
            port.setSerialPortParams(115200, SerialPort.DATABITS_8,
                    SerialPort.STOPBITS_1, SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        }

        BufferedReader is = null;
        PrintStream os = null;

        try {
            is = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(port.getInputStream()));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Can't open input stream");
            is = null;
        }

        try {
            os = new PrintStream(port.getOutputStream(), true);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Can't open output stream");
            is = null;
        }
        os.print("AT+CMGL=\"ALL\"");
        os.print("\r\n");
        try {
            System.out.println(is.readLine());
            System.out.println(is.readLine());
            System.out.println(is.readLine());
        }

        catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Can't recieve input signals");
        }
        port.close();
    }
}
```

The messages below are what I get from Hyper Terminal.

```
+CMGL: 1,"REC READ","777",,"15/08/12,11:03:30+28"
Total saldo DompetKu anda adalah 100000
+CMGL: 2,"REC READ","INDOSAT",,"15/08/12,08:00:00+00"
Total saldo DompetKu anda adalah 100000
+CMGL: 3,"REC READ","777",,"15/08/12,11:08:49+28"
Total saldo DompetKu anda adalah 100000
+CMGL: 4,"REC READ","777",,"15/08/12,16:24:49+28"
Total saldo DompetKu anda adalah 100000
+CMGL: 5,"REC READ","777",,"15/08/12,16:31:36+28"
Total saldo DompetKu anda adalah 100000
+CMGL: 6,"REC READ","777",,"15/08/12,16:32:58+28"
Total saldo DompetKu anda adalah 100000
+CMGL: 7,"REC READ","777",,"15/08/12,16:34:15+28"
Total saldo DompetKu anda adalah 100000
+CMGL: 8,"REC READ","777",,"15/08/12,16:41:00+28"
Total saldo DompetKu anda adalah 100000
+CMGL: 9,"REC READ","777",,"15/08/12,16:42:54+28"
Total saldo DompetKu anda adalah 100000
+CMGL: 10,"REC READ","777",,"15/08/12,16:45:18+28"
Total saldo DompetKu anda adalah 100000
```

How can I get same result in Java?

Answer (score 1):

First a general remark: you should be able to  get access to your port with that simple request:

```
String String wantedPortName = "COM17";= "COM17";
try {
    CommPortIdentifier portId = CommPortIdentifier(wantedPortName);
}
catch(NoSuchPortException ex) {
    System.err.println("Could not find serial port " + wantedPortName);
    System.exit(0);
}
```

But your real problem is that you only read 3 lines from the serial port, instead of looping to read everything. The hard part when reading serial ports, is that you can hardly know whether data is about to arrive. There are two common ways to deal with it:

1. your driver supports read timeout:

   first enable it:

   ```
   port.enableReceiveTimeout(2000); // assume 2 s is long enough to wait
   if (! port.isReceiveTimeout) {
       System.out.println("Receive timeout is not supported");
       port.close(); // maybe more housekeeping is needed...
       System.exit(0);
   }
   ```

   next just loop until an empty read (beware untested in Java):

   ```
   os.print("AT+CMGL=\"ALL\"");
   os.print("\r\n");
   try {
       String line;
       while(true) {
           line = is.readLine());
           if (is.isEmpty()) { break; }
           System.out.println(is.readLine());
   }
   catch (IOException e) {
       System.err.println("Can't recieve input signals");
   }
   ```
2. use one dedicated thread to process input lines and kill it where there nothing more to process.